# Swift protocol similar to Equatable

Tags: cocoa, swift, swift-protocols

I’m trying to create a protocol for types that are Lerp-able (linear-interpolatable). I’m declaring it similarly to how `Equatable` is defined:

```
protocol Lerpable {
    func lerp(from: Self, to: Self, alpha: Double) -> Self
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to implement `Lerpable` for `Double`:

```
func lerp(from: Double, to: Double, alpha: Double) -> Double {
    return from + alpha * (to - from)
}
extension Double: Lerpable {}
```

I get an error: `Type 'Double' does not conform to protocol 'Lerpable'`.

I assumed this would be pretty straightforward, but maybe I just don’t understand how Equatable works. Or is it a special case in Swift? Any thoughts?

---

*UPDATE:* The correct answer is [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930729/swift-protocol-similar-to-equatable/29931307#29931307), and here’s the final version of the code, for others’ reference:

```
protocol Lerpable {
    func lerp(to: Self, alpha: Double) -> Self
}

extension Double: Lerpable {
    func lerp(to: Double, alpha: Double) -> Double {
        return self + alpha * (to - self)
    }
}

func lerp<T: Lerpable>(from: T, to: T, alpha: Double) -> T {
    return from.lerp(to, alpha: alpha)
}
```

I added the global `lerp` function so I could still refer to it as
`lerp(foo, bar, alpha: 0.5)`
rather than
`foo.lerp(bar, alpha: 0.5)`

Comment: why isnt the function inside the extension?

Comment: @ad121 Because I didn’t want it to be constrained to being a member function on Lerpables. Then I realized I could add a global `lerp` function to call the member function anyway. Also: that’s how `func ==` is defined for Equatable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix your problem you need to put the `lerp` function inside your `extension`, like so:

```
extension Double: Lerpable {
    func lerp(from: Double, to: Double, alpha: Double) -> Double {
        return from + alpha * (to - from)
    }
}
```

If you have a look at the `Equatable` `protocol`:

```
protocol Equatable {
    func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}
```

The reason you declare its method (`==` specifically) outside your type `extension` is because `Equatable` wants you to overload an operator and operators **must** be declared at global scope. Here's an example to clarify:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func *** (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}
```

Now to make `Int` adopt the protocol:

```
extension Int : MyProtocol {}

infix operator *** {}
func *** (lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int {
    return lhs * rhs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may further abstract the implementation by adding a typealias for the progress value 't'

```
public protocol Lerpable {
    typealias LerpProgressType
    func lerpTo(value: Self, t: LerpProgressType) -> Self
}
public func lerp<T:Lerpable>(from: T, _ to: T, _ t: T.LerpProgressType) -> T {
    return from.lerpTo(to, t: t)
}

// implementations
extension Double : Lerpable {
    public typealias LerpProgressType = Double
    public func lerpTo(value: Double, t: Double) -> Double {
        return (1.0 - t) * self + t * value
    }
}
extension Float : Lerpable {
    public typealias LerpProgressType = Float
    public func lerpTo(value: Float, t: Float) -> Float {
        return (1.0 - t) * self + t * value
    }
}
extension CGFloat : Lerpable {
    public typealias LerpProgressType = CGFloat
    public func lerpTo(value: CGFloat, t: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return (1.0 - t) * self + t * value
    }
}
```

You can now also extend various structs (such as CGPoint, CGSize, CGRect, CATransform3D, etc.):

```
extension CGPoint : Lerpable {
    public typealias LerpProgressType = CGFloat
    public func lerpTo(value: CGPoint, t: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        return
            CGPoint(
                x: x.lerpTo(value.x, t),
                y: y.lerpTo(value.y, t)
            )
    }
}
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D : LinearInterpolation {
    public typealias LerpProgressType = CLLocationDegrees
    public func lerpTo(value: CLLocationCoordinate2D, t: CLLocationDegrees) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return
            CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                latitude:  latitude.lerpTo(value.latitude, t),
                longitude: longitude.lerpTo(value.longitude, t)
            )
    }
}
```

To implement linear interpolation in generic structs:

```
public struct ValueRange<T> {
    public var start:T
    public var end:T
}

extension ValueRange where T:Lerpable {
    public func lerp(t: T.LerpProgressType) -> T {
        return start.lerpTo(end, t: t)
    }
}
```